# Interaction between 2 Applications using Messaging System

Tags: spring, redis, apache-kafka

I am trying to pass data between 2 or more spring applications. For this i was using Spring AMQP with RabbitMQ.
Now i also need Pub-Sub Architecture where All the subscriber should get the message.
Currently in RabbitMQ Pub-Sub arch works creating of each queue for each consumer. This i dont want .

I am also looking at the list of Pub-Sub Messaging System which will solve my issue.

```
       Publisher------>Data----->Subscriber 1
                           ----->Subscriber 2
```

- REDIS
- APACHE KAFKA

Please suggest the best Messaging System

Answer (score 0):

Apache Kafka is a good contender for publish-subscribe model.

Kafka can work on both models : **traditional queuing** and **publish-subscribe.**

There is a concept of Kafka **consumer groups** which needs to be specified by the Kafka consumer or subscriber while subscribing.

> If all the consumer instances have different consumer groups, then
>   this works like publish-subscribe and all messages are broadcast to
>   all consumers.

References:
https://kafka.apache.org/08/introduction.html